# Java repaint() not calling paintComponent

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, jpanel, repaint

I'm trying to call my paintComponent method by using repaint but it is never being called. This is my first class:

```
public class start
    {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Frame f = new Frame();
        f.createFrame();
    }
}
```

And this is the class that I want the paintComponent method to be called to but all that happens is a blank frame appears:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

 public class newFrame implements Runnable,ActionListener
 {
JFrame window = new JFrame("Frame");
int i = 0;
Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();
public void createFrame(){
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 700, 500);
    window.setFocusable(true);
    window.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    window.setVisible(true);
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

public void run(){
    Timer timer = new Timer (17,this);
    timer.start();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    myCanvas.updateGame();
    myCanvas.render();
    window.add(myCanvas);
}
}

class Canvas extends JPanel{
int x = 10;
int y = 10;
public void updateGame(){
    x++;
}

public void render(){
    repaint();
    System.out.println("Output1");
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g.drawString("hi",x,y);
    System.out.println("Output1");
}
}
```

Output1 is printed multiple times but Output2 is never printed. Why isn't the paintComponent method being called by repaint?

Comment: Looks like you have `"Output1"` in both places...

Comment: Not likely your problem, but it is very odd to start a new Thread just to create a swing timer and schedule a job on it. Just create and start the timer in the createFrame method. Get rid of the Thread/Runnable interface.

Comment: @River is right. That is the correct answer. All you need to do is fix that

Comment: Move window.add(canvas) to the constructor, you don't need to do this 60 times a second

Comment: You might try drawing your `String` at `x=100`, `y=100` instead. Sometimes the very upper left corner is out of vision.

Answer (score 3):

You only have `"Ouput1"` printed *ever*. There is no `"Output2"` printed anywhere.

Comment: Seen as I can't see the whole code, my "suspicion" is that they are creating multiple windows, but not showing the right one

Answer (score 1):

The core problem is within your `ActionListener`...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    myCanvas.updateGame();
    myCanvas.render();
    window.add(myCanvas);
}
```

When you call `window.add`, the `JFrame` has to first remove `myCanvas` and then re-add it, revalidate the layout and schedule a repaint, all of this is taking time, in the mean time, you've jumped in repeated the process, setting a situation in which the framework simply can't keep up with you.

Instead, add `window.add(myCanvas);` to the constructor

```
public void createFrame() {
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 700, 500);
    window.setFocusable(true);
    window.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.add(myCanvas);
    Timer timer = new Timer(17, this);
    timer.start();
}
```

Also, there is simply no need to use a `Thread` to start a `Timer`, it's just confusing the issue.

Beware that Java already has classes called `Frame` and `Canvas`, which could add additional confusion to some developers (especially those who don't have access to the source)